# How do I operate thousands of multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I work in the insurance company, with data that illustrate the future monthly cash-flows.

Due to the report requirement, I would have to print out cash-flows for 200,000 agents separately. Furthermore, since I'm in life insurance, the maximum column number need would be 105 years * 12 month = 1260 columns. Plus some prefix columns for marking agents and cash-flow types.

So the results would be I'm facing 1000+ columns and I would need to have a easy way to produce some usual sql function such as sum by different agents.

Thank you for anyone who can provide any ideas on this!

Comment: Then I would have 200,000 more columns........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your data needs to get smaller (split it up) or you need to choose a different method or tool.

You're not going to get the column limits you need in Oracle or SQL Server or MySQL or Postgresql. They all have row size limits (both bytes & column count) that are too small for what you're trying to do.

A custom app would do it. Most modern languages are limited only by memory size and you can have as many rows and columns as you need when you define the data structure.

Or if you have money, you can look into Google & Amazon's Big Data services. They routinely use huge datasets.

Comment: I searched, the maximum rowsize would be 1.6TB, which is way to enough for storing the information. If I write my own program, the cost on UI, realization of sum, add and other method would be way more than simply apply the database. Furthermore, to coach others would be a pain........

Comment: The rowsize isn't the problem The number of columns is.

Comment: Yep you are right, since the row size is limited to one tuple and the cashflow is in double type (Non-TOASTable) database will not accept it. Furthermore, there seems to be no solution for that except re-compile it from source.

Comment: @Shore: If this is a real insurance company, now is the time to kick the problem back to management and tell them what's going on. Once you move to a DB version that you have recompiled with different constants and data structures & sizes, there are no assurances about it's behavior or accuracy, and they need to know this. It will probably be OK, but if it's not, everything will point back to you, personally. Also, if you're an employee, you have very little personal liability. If you're any sort of contractor or consultant, you're wide open for lawsuits.

Comment: Well, I reconstructed the table, using array to hold all 1272 future cash flow projection with different types, which would be toast out to other tuples so it only cost 8 byte for a pointer. Also created a unnest() view to speed up the sum. For now it is ok and the running time cost is fully acceptable. I do not know with the product increasing (reporting has to be by product by agent), if it will hold the similar function. But in the worst case I can split products out, LOL~~

Answer (score 1):

write a view that pivots the data into the 1000+ column form and then select your reports from that view.

Comment: hmmm, then I couldn't use the sum function to perform certain calc. The thing is, I would need to add up the cashflows by agents, sub-agents and other reporting output, and doing calculation for further purpose.